# Pick an account after Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'd like to write a PowerShell script which will update Teams members from input list/object. However if I run Connect-MicrosoftTeams command (to authenticate/connect to cloud service) for the first time I am asked to pick an account to use for login. This is an issue since I would like this script to be run as scheduled job. Is there a way how to avoid this when running Connect-MicrosoftTeams command ? Commands I am using:

`$credential = Get-Credential`

`Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential`

[image: Connect-MicrosoftTeams credentials window]

I tried to use "-AccountId "email@address.com" but that didn't help. Of course later I will change Get-Credential to username and encrypted password

***EDIT***

If I run `Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential` on other computer, where I've never been logged in with my account, instead of "Pick an account" window, I get credential window for username and password:
[image: Connect-MicrosoftTeams credentials window]

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-TeamsEnvironmentName` parameter? From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps) _Specify "TeamsGCCH" if your organization is in the GCC High Environment. Specify "TeamsDOD" if your organization is in the DoD Environment._

Comment: Looks like [SSO cannot be enabled in Microsoft Teams](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/teams-single-sign-on-automatic-login-pass-through-auth/m-p/37975)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used other module 'AzureAD' and command 'Add-AzureADGroupMember':

`# 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString $Password = "01000000d08c9..." | ConvertTo-SecureString`

`$Credentials = (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "user@domain.com", $Password)`

`Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credentials`

`$AZ_USER=Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq 'user@domain.com'"`

`$AZ_GROUP=Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'teams_name'"`

`Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $AZ_GROUP.ObjectId -RefObjectId $AZ_USER.ObjectId`

then I have to wait couple hours until Active Directory and Teams got synchronized and users were added to AD groups / Teams teams. It's not ideal, but it works with saved credentials and with no user interaction.

Answer (score 3):

As commented, this is certainly a dissapointment, but Single-Sign-On cannot be enabled in Microsoft Teams.

See [the discussion here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/teams-single-sign-on-automatic-login-pass-through-auth/m-p/37975)

Answer (score 2):

This should achieve what you're trying to do.

Credits to: https://www.jaapbrasser.com/quickly-and-securely-storing-your-credentials-powershell/

Save Credentials

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Credential | Export-CliXml -Path "<File path/name to save credentials"
```

Connect using saved credentials through MS Teams PowerShell

```
$Credential = Import-CliXml -Path "<path of exported credential>"
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId "<email>" -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I mentioned it in my question that I tried it too.

Answer (score 0):

For that I always use this from Jaap Brasser:

https://www.jaapbrasser.com/quickly-and-securely-storing-your-credentials-powershell/

Comment: Although I can save credentials to a file using Export-Clixml, it still asks for an account to pick. Thanks for showing me how to export credentials though.

Comment: You need credentials to log on MSTeams, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that even though I provide credentials, I am still asked to pick an account in new windows that pops up after I run 'Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential'